# Как выводить дробное число не в научном формате, без показателя степени

Tags: c++, вывод, форматирование

[image]

Вот мой код :

```
cout << endl << "Cортування неупорядкованого масиву з  " << N << " елементами зайняло часу :  ";
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    A[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;

}
auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
sort2(A, N);
auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - begin;
cout << elapsed.count() << " с" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Comment: +1 за слово "дробовое"

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << elapsed.count() << " с" << endl;
```

Где-то так. Точность выставляйте побольше, а то есть риск увидеть только нули...

Comment: Я бы посоветовал - работайте с нано(ну, микро...)секундами. Не переводите данные в секунды раньше времени. `long long` вам хватит для 50 лет времени :), не волнуйтесь. А уже потом, по окончании работы - накопления статистики, усреднения, выяснения погрешности - выводите в тех единицах, которые вам по душе. А числа - вы же их и получаете - `elapsed.count()`